# HP Pavilion DV2000 web camera driver

Tags: drivers, hp, camera

I got this information using `lsusb`:

> Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0c45:62c0 Microdia Sonix USB 2.0 Camera

I have problem with my camera. When I use web camera in supported application, like Bandoo chat application at facebook, or any web page with camera support.

I have installed cheese or luvcview. Both are working on my laptop but when I use web based application with camera support, then application fails to detect my camera.

Is there any problem with my camera driver? I have not installed specific driver.

Answer (score 1):

Those websites use camera with Flash. You can try installing Flash, if it's not yet installed. However, it's not guaranteed that camera works in Ubuntu with Flash. There have been multiple problems with that earlier.

Also, check out [Flash settings](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager06.html). You can add exceptions for specific sites to allow using camera (it's security feature that camera usage is restricted; otherwise Flash add could use your video camera).